Best Practices for Updating Stats with MongoDB, Redis, and RabbitMQ in Spring Boot
I’m building a Spring Boot application using MongoDB, RabbitMQ, and Redis. The app tracks stats (e.g., OS versions, device types) and updates them as new data arrives.
Current Approach:

Device data is saved immediately to the devices collection.
Updates to the stats collection are sent to RabbitMQ as events.
A consumer processes these events and updates the stats collection in MongoDB immediately.
After MongoDB is updated, the Redis cache is refreshed.

Maybe it can be done like this:

Update Redis immediately after processing.
Batch-sync Redis to MongoDB periodically (e.g., at the end of the day).

Question:

Is updating MongoDB first and then Redis the best practice? Does anyone use the alternative approach?

DEVICE REGISTER:

    fun updateUser(request: UserUpdateRequest): BaseResponse {
        val device = Device(
            deviceUuid = request.device.deviceUuid,
            deviceBrand = request.device.deviceBrand?.lowercase(),
            deviceModel = request.device.deviceModel?.lowercase(),
            osName = request.device.osName?.lowercase(),
            osVersion = request.device.osVersion,
            appVersion = request.device.appVersion,
            sdkVersion = request.device.sdkVersion,
            userUuid = request.userUuid,
            lastUpdated = LocalDateTime.now())

        deviceRepository.save(device)
        //PUBLISH TO RABBITMQ FOR STATS COLLECTION UPDATE
        deviceEventProducer.sendDeviceEvent(device)
        SuccessResponse ("User created successfully")
    }

HANDLE DEVICE STATS UPDATE EVENT:
@Service
class DeviceEventConsumer(
    private val customStatsRepository: CustomStatsRepository
) {

    @RabbitListener(queues = ["deviceEventsQueue"])
    fun handleDeviceEvent(message: DeviceEventMessage) {
        println("handleDeviceEvent() -> device: $message")

        val merchantId = message.merchantId ?: return
            customStatsRepository.incrementOsStats(merchantId, message.device.osName!!)
            customStatsRepository.incrementOsVersion(merchantId, message.device.osVersion!!)
            customStatsRepository.incrementDeviceDetails(
                merchantId,
                message.device.deviceBrand!!,
                message.device.deviceModel!!
            )
        customStatsRepository.updateLastUpdated(merchantId)
    }
}


IMO the approach you have described looks OK. In case if MongoDB is source of truth, Redis should be updated afterwards. 
What about the question, how often Sync between MongDB and Redis should be done, it depends of application business needs(mean how long final customer can accept old data) and also how often a device entity is updated during the day, if it is multiple times, will be better to send an end of day update. 
About Sync approach, I would sugget you to have a look at this article. Even if it is written for Kafka, you can get an idea of how to decouple Document update, from publishing an update notification to RabbitMq, by tailing oplog replica set MongoDB collection.
